# Issue with running vuforia sample code

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, vuforia

I'm struggling to implement vuforia sample code. I downloaded vuforia iOS [SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk/%22SDK%22) and [sample](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples?d=windows-31-22-5/%22Sample%20Code%22) code and put the sample code in sample directory of the sdk subfolder. When i run the application it shows so many errors. Below i'm attaching two image of my folder structure and error messages. Please help me out. Thanks.

Error :

[image]

Sample folder structure : 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to put a new folder between the folders, VuforiaSamples and samples, just put your .zip sample file on samples directory of Vuforia and open there, for look like the image:

[image: Folders directory]
And try to run on real device

Comment: its okay, but how can i add vuforia sdk in my existing project and make it workable ? when i drag and drop vuforia sdk and classes, xcode shows classes not found

Comment: Solved my problem Thanks